# Android - Override DNS for dynamic IP

Tags: android, networking

I want to make use of my own DNS on Android in general. Whether the IP is static or taken via DHCP. So I put the

```
Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS1, mIP);
```

But then I suppose it works only for static IP.

How can I override the DNS setting for every case?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: The DHCP settings indicate the DNS Server for the client to use.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution may be to have your application perform the DNS lookups itself using:

[DNS Service Provider for the Java Naming Directory Interface™ (JNDI)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/jndi/jndi-dns.html)